# Adding a Keyboard Shortcut to Google Chrome and/or Firefox for clicking "Add Destination" in Google Maps

Tags: google-chrome, macros, google-chrome-devtools, keyboard-shortcuts

Attempting to select the "Add Destination" button on Google Maps without the use of the mouse. If I could keep my hands from leaving the keyboard it'd save a lot of time.

https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Fond+du+Lac,+WI/Constantine,+MI/@42.6647403,-88.7996682,8z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x8803f62a149e9925:0x9404d0e850d903cd!2m2!1d-88.4470508!2d43.7730448!1m5!1m1!1s0x8816fe20f2f853c3:0x3b820ac9f25eab5e!2m2!1d-85.6686026!2d41.8411603!3e0?entry=ttu

So, for any given page such as this, I'd be able to use said Shortcut to automatically select the Add Destination button on the webpage.

Not much of a coder, so I've tried recording a macro for it with browser extensions iMacros and Wildfire and that didn't produce the desired result. Perhaps there is something a more experienced user can do with them.

I'm simply wanting it to Add a Destination each time I use the keyboard shortcut on the Google Maps web page.

Comment: Answered my own question.

Whilst in the Google Maps browser page, after inputting your initial two locations, Press Enter, then hit Ctrl + Shift + D and it will add a destination input box after your latest entry.  Unfortunately, this also pulls up the browser's default "Add Bookmark" window. Press Esc to leave this window and add your destination.

Not a perfect solution, but it does accomplish what I originally sought.